# react-native link for fonts - only link fonts

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to link a large number of font files into my react-native project and I don't want to do it manually because of how many there are.

Most instructions I've found say to do this:

## package.json

```
"rnpm": {
 "assets": ["assets/fonts"]
}
```

and then `react-native link`

The problem is I can't run `react-native link` without a second argument as it causes problems with some of the libraries I have installed.

Is there a way I can specify the command so it only links assets?

Comment: I think `react-native link` command in cli version 1.x has a bug that it links all native modules along with assets and vice-versa. They have fixed this command in cli version 2.x. To try it for RN >= 0.60 you'll need to upgrade your cli using [these instructions](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#updating-the-cli). Alternatively, if you're on RN < 0.60 you may want to [check this util](https://github.com/unimonkiez/react-native-asset) or do asset linking manually for ios/android as last resort.

Comment: Did you find the solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

first edit your `package.json`

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

then run

> react-native link ./assets/fonts

[source](https://medium.com/@mehran.khan/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4)

Comment: I just get `error Failed to get dependency config.`

Comment: make sure `./assets/fonts/` is the correct path, for me it is `./src/assets/fonts/`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution without running `react-native link` either. My solution was to commit everything, clean your stage, run `react-native link`, then check the git diff and remove the ones that is not your fonts. Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

**For example:**

**package.json**

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/Fonts/"
    ]
  },
```

now you can use

> react-native link

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Not to be rude, but read my questions again, I cleary state that I *can't* do `react-native link`

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked for me:

Create a configuration file `react-native.config.js` in the root project directory and add the code below:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

Then run `npx react-native link`

Here is the article: https://medium.com/@aravindmnair/add-custom-fonts-to-react-native-0-60-easily-in-3-steps-fcd71459f4c9